# Magento 1.9.1.1: blank page on product save

Tags: magento

After updating to 1.9.1.1, when I tried to save a product after editing it I've got a blank page.

After uncommenting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`,  I've got an error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::getProductRuleIds()`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please share the whole call stack

Comment: found the problem in a local override of  \app\code\local\Mage\CatalogRule\Model\Resource\Rule.php. I solved using the new file keeping customization

Comment: Post as an answer :-) nice work

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in a local override of \app\code\local\Mage\CatalogRule\Model\Resource\Rule.php.
I solved using the new file and bringing my customizations.